# Как создать датасет для ultralytics classify?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Обычный .yaml файл работает только для детекции. Как создать файл для классификации или по другому передать данные для тренировки. В официальной документации используют mnist160. Его передают как параметр, но про его устройство и структуру я ничего не нашел. Даже не очень понятно папка это или тег.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Речь идет про yolov8n-cls